# Unable to render R Markdown in an R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to generate a report where I want to output the tables and the charts across multiple tabs from the Shiny app. Below is my code for shiny app and markdown. When I try to download the report I dont get the plot but just the R code. How can I render the outputs in the downloadable report .

`app.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(rmarkdown)


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id = "tab",
              menuItem("1", tabName = "1"),
              menuItem("2", tabName = "2"),
              downloadButton("report", "Generate report")

  )
)
body <-   ## Body content
  dashboardBody(box(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "1",
              fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput("atc_topline"))

      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "2",
              fluidRow(  plotlyOutput("stack"))
      )
    )
  ))

ui <-   dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Scorecard"),
                      sidebar,
                      body)

# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  delta_plot <- data.frame(structure(list(Month = structure(c(17257, 17287, 17318, 17348,
 17379, 17410, 17440, 17471, 17501, 17532), class = "Date"),  Interacting = c(11.326863, 11.21184,
  11.004666, 11.045412, 11.413678, 11.487366, 11.069, 11.177319,12.214473, 11.965812), Switcher = c(1.065518, 1.2053, 1.078746,
                                      0.792034, 0.945035, 1.086651, 1.334486, 0.919187, 0.683544, 0.875269
  )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
 vars = "Month", drop = TRUE, indices = list( 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), group_sizes = c(1L,
                  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
                   Month = structure(c(17257, 17287, 17318, 17348, 17379, 17410,
                   17440, 17471, 17501, 17532), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA,  -10L),
                  class = "data.frame", vars = "Month", drop = TRUE), na.action = structure(c(`11` = 11L), class = "omit")))

  output$stack <- renderPlotly({
    p <- plot_ly()

    ToAdd <- setdiff(colnames(delta_plot),"Month")

    for(i in ToAdd[2:3]){
      p <- p %>% add_trace(x = delta_plot$Month, y = delta_plot[[i]], name = i,
                           type = 'scatter',
                           mode = 'lines') %>% layout(yaxis = list( side = "right"))
    }
p
  })

  output$atc_topline <- renderDataTable({
    delta_plot

  })

  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
    filename = "report.html",
    content = function(file) {

      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      params <- list(n = delta_plot)


      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

`report.Rmd`

````
---
title: "Dynamic report"
output: html_document
params:
  n: NA
---

```{r}
library(plotly)
renderPlotly({
      p <- plot_ly()

    ToAdd <- setdiff(colnames(params$n),"Month")

    for(i in ToAdd[2:3]){
      p <- p %>% add_trace(x = params$n$Month, y = params$n[[i]], name = i,
                           type = 'scatter',
                           mode = 'lines') %>% layout(yaxis = list( side = "right"))
    }
p
  })
```
````

Comment: Are you expecting the RMD output to run on a shiny server? I think you need to remove the `runtime: shiny` from the YAML. Or place the file in a directory where RMD files can run off the server.

Comment: Eventually it might be hosted on  ` r connect server` or `shinyappsio` . I did remove the runtime and still get the downloaded report where I get the code and not the rendered plot.

Comment: Ok, try removing the `renderPlotly()` function or combine it with the `plotlyOutpu()` funciton.

Comment: Still doesnt work

Comment: I just modified my question using the params and adding the library but it still doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: Add `params` to your YAML, please. Tutorial here: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports

Comment: I did follow the same as the tutorial which I have edited above.Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the following markdown document I am getting the R-code and the plotly plot.
I just removed the `renderPlotly({ })` and the whitespaces before `title`, which caused this Yaml problem, as described [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1626):

> Warning: Error in yaml::yaml.load: Parser error: did not find expected
>    at line 2, column 1

````
---
title: "Dynamic report"
output: html_document
params:
  n: NA
---

```{r}
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly()

ToAdd <- setdiff(colnames(params$n),"Month")

for(i in ToAdd[2:3]){
  p <- p %>% add_trace(x = params$n$Month, y = params$n[[i]], name = i,
                       type = 'scatter',
                       mode = 'lines') %>% layout(yaxis = list( side = "right"))
}
p

```
````

[image]